# How to fix Class 'AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>' has no instance getter 'length'?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have this error:

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building AnnouncementList(dirty):
Class 'AsyncSnapshot' has no instance getter 'length'.
Receiver: Instance of 'AsyncSnapshot'
Tried calling: length

My code:

```dart
          FutureBuilder(
                      future: Provider.of<AnnouncementProvider>(context)
                          .fetchAnnouncements(authToken!),
                      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return const Center(
                            child: Text('An error has occurred!'),
                          );
                        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          print(snapshot);
                          return AnnouncementList(snapshot);
                        } else {
                          return const Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        }
                      })
```

this is my AnnouncementList code:

```dart
class AnnouncementList extends StatelessWidget {
  final data;

  AnnouncementList(this.data);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(data);
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              _tile(data.results[index].title, 'aa'),
              Divider(
                thickness: 4,
                indent: 0,
                endIndent: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.4,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(198, 158, 96, 1),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to remove this error:

1. Define a type for the `data` variable. (Something like `final List<T> data;` where `T` is your type of list)

```dart
class AnnouncementList extends StatelessWidget {
  final data;  // Here
```

2. When sending the `snapshot` data into `AnnouncementList`, make sure to typecast it using `as` operator into a `List` and then casting it to your list type. (`return AnnouncementList((snapshot as List).cast<T>);`)

```dart
                        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          print(snapshot);
                          return AnnouncementList(snapshot);  // Here
                        }
```

Comment: hi, thank you so much for trying to help! i've fixed my code.

Comment: Hey! If my answer helped, you can accept it as an answer.

Comment: sorry, im using my own solution, but sure why not @happy_san

Comment: You can always post the solution yourself and mark that as answer. :)